# Why am I gettting object Promise trying to use Slack search.messages?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Slack API noob here. Trying this out, I gave scope access to user and using user token instead of bot, this is only for testing purposes for now. But I get 'object Promise' on the console. I've tried a few different approaches using .then but haven't been able to figure it out. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help, please let me know if you need any additional details.

```
const result = app.client.search.messages({
    token: user_token,
    query: "Hello world in:testing"
  });
console.log ("result: " + result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read up on how Javascript promises work.

Simply put though, `result` here is a Promise, which is why you are getting that returned in your `console.log`. A promise is basically an incomplete request that is designed to happen asynchronously. So whilst your code is off making a http request it doesn't wait around, and just runs onward.

You can resolve this by either using `async/await` (which may also deserve some research), that looks like this:

```
async function () => {
const result = await app.client.search.messages({
    token: user_token,
    query: "Hello world in:testing"
  });
console.log(result)
}
```

Or you can use promise chaining (`then`), like this:

```
const result = app.client.search.messages({
    token: user_token,
    query: "Hello world in:testing"
  })
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(err => console.err(err))
```

You can chain multiple `then`s together, and the `catch` is in case the request errors.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `app.client.search.message` returns a javascript promise instead of your search result. Basically, the result of your search isn't ready immediately (it's gotta talk on the interwebs to answer your search), so the slack API is returning a promise instead.

Promises are a whole can of worms. This seems like a fairly decent quick start guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-javascript-promises

## Approach 1: async await

The quickest way to get what you want would be to use the `await` keyword.
This basically says "please wait until this is done and then give me the result"

so this might get you one step closer to what you want:

```js
async function myFunction() {

// do some other stuff

const result = await app.client.search.messages({
    token: user_token,
    query: "Hello world in:testing"
  });

console.log(result)

// do some other stuff
}
```

Why did I wrap your code in an `async` `function` you ask? It's because the await keyword can only be used in async functions. This has a problem you'll have to deal with in that if you simply call an async function like `myFunction()` it will return *before it is done executing*. This can cause a race condition (actually, just a sequence error in JS if you want to be pedantic, but it's rarely useful to make that distinction). You could also `await` `myFunction()`, but then you're in the same problem as before.

Race conditions / dealing with async functions are too big of a subject to tackle here.

SO. that leads me to

## Approach 2: the `.then()`

It sounds like you already started trying to use `.then`. I'll try to give an example of how you might want to use it.

```js
// I'm storing the promise in a variable instead of calling .then immediately
// it might make this example easier to understand
const resultPromise = app.client.search.messages({
    token: user_token,
    query: "Hello world in:testing"
  });

function doSomethingWithTheResult (result) {
    console.log ("result: " + result);
}

resultPromise.then(doSomethingWithTheResult);
// notice we ARE NOT calling doSomethingWithTheResult
// we are simply telling the promise what function to call when it's done.
```

The example above uses a bit more variables than people usually use. The code below is basically the same, but a little more compact

```js
app.client.search.messages({
    token: user_token,
    query: "Hello world in:testing"
})
  .then(function (result) { // you could also use an arrow function here
    console.log(result)
  })
```

## Important Note!

```js
const resultPromise = app.client.search.messages({
    token: user_token,
    query: "Hello world in:testing"
})
  .then(function (result) {
      // CODE HERE GETS EXECUTED SECOND (in most cases)
  })
// CODE HERE GETS EXECUTED BEFORE CODE IN THE THEN (in most cases)
```

## Important Note 2: Error handling

### async await

```js
try {
   const result = await funcThatReturnsAPromise()
}
catch (e) {
   // something bad happened
   // maybe log the error, or display an error message.
}
```

### `.then()`

```js
funcThatReturnsAPromise()
  .then(function(result) {
     // if here, then we made it
     console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
     // if here, you won't be getting your result today :(
     // maybe log the error or something

  })
```